# How to resolve Table must have at least one visible column issue while creating table?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS OLYMPIC_HISTORY;
(
id INT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR,
sex VARCHAR,
age VARCHAR,
height VARCHAR,
weight VARCHAR,
team VARCHAR,
noc VARCHAR,
games VARCHAR,
year INT,
season VARCHAR,
city VARCHAR,
sport VARCHAR,
event VARCHAR,
medal VARCHAR
);
```

Error:

```
A Table must have at least one visible column
```

How to fix the error and process too?

Comment: Try removing the first semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

You have following issues:

1. The semicolon in the first line must be removed
2. The varchar columns require a maximum length, meaning you need to write for example `varchar(100)` instead of `varchar` only
3. `Year` and `Event` should not be used as column name because they are SQL key words. This can cause further problems.

Issue 1 and 2 must be solved, otherwise your create table command will fail.

Issue 3 should be solved in order to avoid further difficulties.

So a correct create table command will be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS OLYMPIC_HISTORY
(
id INT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(100),
sex VARCHAR(100),
age VARCHAR(3),
height VARCHAR(100),
weight VARCHAR(100),
team VARCHAR(100),
noc VARCHAR(100),
games VARCHAR(100),
eventYear INT,
season VARCHAR(100),
city VARCHAR(100),
sport VARCHAR(100),
olympicEvent VARCHAR(100),
medal VARCHAR(100)
);
```

Furthermore, it is strange you want almost all columns to be varchar. Columns like the age, height or weight are usually numeric. Mabye you should change this, too.